# Как найти k точек максимально удаленных друг от друга

Tags: python, геометрия

Имеется множество из n точек на плоскости. Необходимо найти k таких точек, расстояние между которыми наибольшее. При k=2 все просто, при k>2 простым перебором получается слишком долго.

Может есть какие-нибудь алгоритмы или даже что-нибудь реализованное? Пишу на python.

Comment: Во-первых, уточните, что вы понимаете под расстоянием между k точек для k>2 ? Сумма всех пар расстояний?

Comment: @Александр, да. Чтобы точки были наиболее удалены друг от друга

Comment: у вас подразумевается координатная плоскость? Если так, то всё будет просто

Comment: @ivanK, да, координатная

Comment: @ИльданКиамов, ну тогда просто берете максимальное значение по оси Х и по оси Y, и аналогично минимальное значение по осям. Также нужно найти будет для макс. оХ, мин. oY и мин oX и макс oY. После чего вам достаточно будет расчитать растояние примерно для 4 точек